# Lambda context vs lambda function as shown in AWS X-Ray service maps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nodes, trace, aws-xray

Lambda context vs lambda function as shown in AWS X-Ray service maps?

In AWS X-ray service maps a lambda trace has two nodes: Lambda context and lambda function.
Why are they two and what does each mean/do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AWS Lambda Context**: This is an object that is prepared before calling the actual function handler, this object consists of info about invocation, function, and execution environment. (this will consume negligible time of course)

**AWS Lambda Function**: Here the actual function code execution breakdown will be there.

For more info go through [Lambda Context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html)